# LinuxMint "File System" shows no space when many GB exist

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, virtual-machine, disk

I have a VM running LinuxMint 17.1. I just resized the virtual disk, then used a live CD to resize the system partitions. I now have 18GB+ free. However, when I look in Files, "File System" shows as full. I also have been getting warnings that I only have 147MB free. But there's plenty of space, it's almost as if I need to "refresh" something so it notices that I resized the partition. See below:

[image: Plenty of Space]

```
josh@LinuxMintVM ~ $ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root  9.5G  8.9G   92M 100% /
none                       4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                       2.0G  8.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                      396M  1.1M  395M   1% /run
none                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                       2.0G   42M  1.9G   3% /run/shm
none                       100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1                  9.8G  1.6G  7.8G  17% /home
/dev/sda1                  236M   83M  141M  37% /boot
shared                     932G  134G  799G  15% /media/sf_shared
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your using LVM, so you have to expand your current drive after you have resized it. check the following link.
[resize on the fly] 
http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/features/resize-your-disks-on-the-fly-with-lvm

Comment: Ah, right - I think I ran into this issue before. Thanks! I used `system-config-lvm` to resize the partition.